# Convenient way to test custom DB from Assets using ProviderTestCase2

Tags: android, junit

I am testing ContentProvider using ProviderTestCase2.

To do this, I created assets folder and I am storing prepared DB there.

On start I am trying to upload this DB to make some test on it, but I cannot get assets folder from AssetsManager since getAssets using getContext is pointing to the tested ContentProvider class, while getAssets using getMockContext throws throws UnsupportedOperationException.

What is the proposed solution to test a custom DB altogether with custom ContentProvider from jUnit tests on Android? ProviderTestCase2 disappointingly doesn't do what I expected it to do?